# Mozilla Firefox - Recovering bookmarks from old Firefox when new version is installed

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I have installed new version of Firefox and from then whenever I open Firefox it crashed. So I have uninstalled Firefox totally from my system and installed version 30 of Firefox but all my book marks etc. have gone.

Is there any way to get my bookmarks back?

Answer (score 4):

Look for bookmarks.html in your profile folder

e.g.

```
 C:\Documents and Settings\Joe\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default\bookmarks.html
```

Mozillazine has an article on recovering [Lost bookmarks](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Lost_bookmarks)

> Firefox automatically makes a bookmark backup every day you use it (up to 5 backups total), with newer backups replacing the older copies. **If you use the profile, you must act quickly, before they are all overwritten.**

Comment: Nice. I was about to claim Firefox doesn't use that HTML file anymore, but apparently those are backups: *Firefox automatically makes a bookmark backup every day you use it (up to 5 backups total), with newer backups replacing the older copies. **If you use the profile, you must act quickly, before they are all overwritten**.*

Comment: Thanks Arjan, I'll amend the answer to include the text you quoted.